# Корень в слове "воин"

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Какой корень в слове ВОИН? В одном источнике нашёл, что корень -ВОЙ- (от ВОЙНА и т. д.) накладывается на суффикс -ИН- (но почему происходит такой процесс? можно ли сказать наоборот: что суффикс наложен на корень?) и получается корень -ВОИ- (но каким образом и зачем?). Но разборы в Интернете выделяют корень -ВОИН- (почему?). Однако слово ВОИТЕЛЬ по всем источникам  идёт с корнем -ВОИ-.

Если ли ещё такие примеры, где корень на суффикс накладывается?

И заключительный вопрос: почему при всём этом разнообразии в школе учили, что корень всегда заканчивается на согласный?

Answer (score 3):

> Какой корень в слове ВОИН?

В некоторых случаях у лингвистов нет единого мнения по поводу членения слова на морфемы. В данном случае с достаточным основанием можно считать корнем и "вой", и "воин". Второе понятнее, но первое ближе к исторической правде.

> В одном источнике нашёл, что корень -ВОЙ- (от ВОЙНА и т. д.)
>   накладывается на суффикс -ИН-

С исторической точки зрения (["диахронический" подход](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) так оно и есть. Вопрос-то в другом. Надо ли для насущных надобностей разбираться в этой истории и обучать ей школьников? Не проще ли пойти по пути закрепления современных реалий, признав чередование И/Й в корне "вой", или вообще узаконив "воин" как самостоятельный корень? Или всё-таки необходимо считаться с традицией и признавать наложение морфем в *современном* слове?!

> (но почему происходит такой процесс?

Ну почему... Потому что язык так устроен. Исторически в русском так сложилось, что сочетание "йи" упрощается до И. Впрочем, произношение [войин] и [воин] настолько мало различается на слух, что бытует мнение о том, что звук Й там реально присутствует. В украинском, например, наоборот: И после гласного кодируется как ЙИ (орфографическое Ї), хотя произношение неотличимо от русского.

> можно ли сказать наоборот: что суффикс наложен на корень?) и
>   получается корень -ВОИ- (но каким образом и зачем?).

Вы немного тут запутались. От перемены мест "наоборот" не получится. Корень и суффикс налагаются друг на друга, это взаимный процесс, от того, что вы назвали первым, результат не изменится.

> Но электронные
>   разборы в Интернете выделяют корень -ВОИН- (почему?). Однако слово
>   ВОИТЕЛЬ по всем источникам идёт с корнем -ВОИ-.

А это я уже сказал. Подходы разные. При том, о котором вы говорите, слова "воитель" и "воин" рассматриваются как исторически родственные, но не однокоренные. Иначе пришлось бы выстраивать развитую систему корневых чередований. В данном случае это совершенно не оправдано.

> Если ли ещё такие примеры, где корень на суффикс накладывается?

Много.

Разберитесь, например, со словом *"взять"/"взимать"*. Вы будете удивлены, узнав, что здесь в результате наложения корня и суффикса развилось совершенно невероятное, казалось бы, корневое чередование я/им.

Или вот еще совсем уж дикий пример того же корне-суффиксного чередования. Слово без корня *"вынуть"*. *"Вы"* - приставка, *"нуть"* - глагольный суффикс (сравните: прыгнуть, крикнуть). А на самом деле это слово восходит к *"выимнуть"*. Первая часть корня *"им"* растворилась в приставке (ы<ыи), вторая - в суффиксе (н<мн).

Еще хороший пример - слово *"обуть"* (и *"обувь"*). В нем корнем считается "у", но ведь "уть" - это очевидный глагольный суффикс! Получилась так потому, что "б" (вставное от приставки) срослось с историческим корнем "оу"/"оув" , а сам этот корень "растворился" в суффиксе. А *"обувь"* по идее имело суффикс "овь" (сравните: свекр/свекровь), которое развилось, видимо, из праславянского "ы" (сравните: морква-морковь из исторического "моркы").

Тут не все бесспорно, можно и возразить по некоторым позициям, но главное, что сама ситуация сращения и наложения корня и суффикса (как частный случай так называемого "морфемного переразложения") - вещь совсем не уникальная.

Понятно, что на полный анализ всех этих явлений ни одного словаря не хватит. Поэтому в словарях приводят обычно некий общепринятый вариант членения на морфемы, руководствуясь обычно современным состоянием языка, а не какими-то  историческими экскурсами. Конечно, это не может не привести к возникновению вопросов, подобных вашему.

> И заключительный вопрос: почему при всём этом разнообразии в школе
>   учили, что корень всегда заканчивается на согласный?

Правила такого нету. Но в огромном большинстве случаев исторический корень в славянских языках состоит из одного слога, который ранее заканчивался на согласный. Это очень древнее фонетическое правило (вернее сказать - закономерность), унаследованное еще со времен славяно-германской языковой общности.

В русском языке это свойство во многом справедливо и для заимствованных корней. Язык как бы подстраивает под себя, свои закономерности, новые слова, исходно этим закономерностям не подчиняющиеся.

В словах "пальто", "кенгуру", "каратэ" по всем законам всё слово состоит из корня. Но язык с этим "не согласен" и "усекает" корень до последней согласной, производя *пальтишко*, *кенгуриный*, *каратист*.

Answer (score 2):

**Из словаря Черных:**

В др.-рус. языке существовало слово **"вой"**, его **старшее** значение является **собирательным**  (то есть войско, рать), от него произошло слово **"воин"**, где ИН — суффикс **единичности**: vojь + inъ.

Кроме того,  употреблялись формы **вой (ед. ч.) — вои** (мн.ч.), где вой (воин) — **младшее** значение слова "вой" (войско).

**Война** происходит от относительного прилагательного к слову **vojь** (войско), поэтому добавлен суффикс n: **vojьnъ**.

**Воевать** — также от vojь, добвлен глагольный суффикс.

И.е. корень у этих слов — **voi/vei** со значением преследовать, нападать, охотиться, схватывать.

В современном языке указанные словообразовательные процессы не отражаются, поэтому суффиксы в словах война и воин не выделяются: **войн/а,**  **воин** (корень + нулевое окончание), **воева/ть.**

Answer (score 1):

Изучить Вам нужно (если хочется лезть в дебри) 
"Русский язык сегодня: Aктуальные вопросы теории и их методическая интерпретация". 
Видимо, главу, относящуюся к вопросу, написала Ирина Михайлова, но её нет среди авторов книги...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот фундаментальный труд я обнаружила только в Гугл-Книгах, откуда копировать нельзя, но **[ссылку дать пробую](https://books.google.ru/books?id=0dofDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=R8P1XhK-Mi&sig=0ruAXfvhUpPQQsaP25caqnRK1rA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN9_CjmZnUAhWGjCwKHawFC_EQ6AEIWDAI#v=onepage&q&f=false)** (кликабельно!) и скрин прилагаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно интересующая Вас проблема называется:

**[СКРЫТЫЙ j (й) НА СТЫКЕ КОРНЯ И СУФФИКСА](https://www.kazedu.kz/referat/40856/3)**

> Основная трудность при изучении случаев, когда j (й) находится на
>   стыке корня и суффикса обусловлена тем, что учащиеся испытывают
>   затруднения в определении истинного корня и суффикса. Часто они
>   относят j (й), который принадлежит корню к суффиксу, в результате чего
>   искажается морфемный строй русского языка.
>
> ---
>
> ...Подобные ошибки возможны не только в случаях, когда разбирается
>   глагол. Они возникают также и при разборе других частей речи. В слове
>   **бо/ец** истинный морфемный состав **бой + ец** (ср.: бойца), **воин** — **вой + ин** (ср.: (вой(ск)а). В слове военный **й** между двумя гласными сливается со звуком **е**; в слове паять — корень пай
>   (ср.: пайка); в слове затеять — корень затей (ср.: затей/ник).

По ссылке можно посмотреть таблицу ("где корень на суффикс накладывается"), в которой подобраны слова со скрытым j (й) на стыке корня и суффикса.

> Цель данной таблицы состоит в том, чтобы наглядно показать частотность
>   встречаемости подобной трудности...

А **[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)** покажет Вам, кто придумал проблему (правда, на примере слова "война"):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понятно, да? Тихонов ему имя.

Макс Фасмер раскрывает этимологию слова:

**[ВОИН](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-2040.htm)**

> укр. во́ïн, др.-русск. воинъ, мн. ч. вои, болг. войни́к "солдат",
>   сербохорв. во̀jни̑к, словен. vojník, чеш., слвц. vojín, voják.

Вот как раз все эти войники с вояками доказывают нам, что не всех словарей нужно слушаться, тем паче электронных разборов, одни из которых прислушиваются к "новатору" Тихонову, другие — к мнению других скромных ученых... А то сразу — почему?

В словах "обувь" (обуть-разуть) и "вынуть" отыщите-ка корень на согласный...

А школа учит, как ей проще.

---

Нашлась чудная картинка к "корню на согласный":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а в итоге какой корень в слове *воин*? Нельзя ли более эксплицитно? И, будьте добры, объясните, каким образом в нашей ситуации полезно знать, что, допустим, по-словенски *воин* — *vojník*?

Comment: Аэр, однокоренные слова! В "войнике" очень хорошо просматривается корень -вой-. А мн. ч. у Фасмера прямо-таки "вои", от ед. ч. "вой". Но йот принадлежит сразу корню и суффиксу, об этом и речь. Поэтому иные учёные рассматривают как корень только -во-.

Comment: А, ясно; мне кажется, что, раз уж приводятся когнаты, то стоит дать кучу дополнительных пояснений, типа "и словенский, и чешский, и украинский (а тут еще непонятная буква ï закралась!) — родственные языки; все эти слова произошли от одной и той же основы" и т. д. и т. п. Где именно "йот принадлежит сразу корню и суффиксу" — в "вой", или "воин", или "война"? (Запутался, прошу прощения.)

Comment: Бестолка ты, Аэрчик! ))) А как минусы лепить - он сразу тут как тут. У меня же всё как по нотам расписано, на все случаи жизни: и что делать, и кто виноват, и как же ж жить! )))

Comment: я уже просил придерживаться официального стиля общения — повторяюсь. Мне, как простому читателю, трудно составить четкую логическую цепочку, используя информацию из вашего ответа, поэтому я и задаю вопросы. Видимо, не стоит. (Вопросы призваны помочь автору ответа улучшить свой текст, не более!)